# Maintaining scroll position while inserting elements above: glitching only in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I have HTML page which contains a lot of sections. Content of these sections is loaded lazily. After page load, user is scrolled to some particular section. Then content above and below the section is loaded and inserted. Obviously inserting content above changes scroll position so I need to maintain scroll position relatively to the current section.

I have implemented the simplest solution which **works perfectly in Chrome, FF, Edge and even IE11** but in Safari - it has glitches.

Here is the code:

```
function insertElementAbove() {
  var elem;

  // load elem

  var prevOffset = window.pageYOffset;
  // insert element
  container.insertBefore(elem, container.firstChild);
  // measure inserter element height and adjust scroll pos
  var elemHeight = elem.offsetHeight;
  window.scrollTo(0, prevOffset + elemHeight);
}
```

I assume that the last 4 lines are run synchronously so according to the browser rendering pipeline no repaint can be done in between:
[image: pipeline]

But in Safari it seems that sometimes paint and composite happens before changing scroll. Why only Safari behaves like this? Can it be because of Safari use `IOSurface` framework (https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/56820)? Are there any ways to solve/workaround this behavior?

---

**Here is [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zMdqcxlnIFgKQRUg6Ka2?p=preview).**

*The issue is **not reproducible in iframe mode** so go to the **"Preview in separate window"** using button in the top-right corner:*

[image: button]

---

- Safari: `Version 10.0.1 (12602.2.14.0.7)`
- macOS Sierra: `Version 10.12.1`